# Tower of Hanoi error

Tags: java, recursion, methods

Alright so I designed a code for the activity "The Towers of Hanoi". It is excellent for recursion exercise. The problem is that when I solve the puzzle via pencil and paper after outputting the results, it turns out to be wrong. 
When n = 2, the puzzle works beautifully. But I just tried n = 3, and something is out of place. 
**My program is designed to make the 3 peg the final place for all the pieces. So the disks all finalize on peg 3.**

```
public class TowersOfHanoi {

    public static String hanoi(int nDisks, int fromPole, int toPole) 
    {
        int helpPole;
        String Pol1, Pol2, MyStep, MyPol; //contains moves

        if(nDisks ==1)
        {
            return "There is " + nDisks + " disk moving from " + fromPole + "==>" + toPole + "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            helpPole = 6 - fromPole - toPole; //fromPole + helpPole + toPole = 6

            Pol1 = hanoi(nDisks-1, fromPole, helpPole);

            MyStep = "There are/is " + (nDisks-1) + " disk(s) moving from " + fromPole + "==>" + toPole + "\n";

            Pol2 = hanoi(nDisks-1, helpPole, toPole);

            MyPol = Pol1 + MyStep + Pol2; //+ = String concatenation

            return MyPol;

         }
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n = 3;
        String StepsToSolution;

        StepsToSolution = hanoi (n, 1, 3);

        System.out.println(StepsToSolution);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
There is 1 disk moving from 1==>3
There are/is 1 disk(s) moving from 1==>2
There is 1 disk moving from 3==>2
There are/is 2 disk(s) moving from 1==>3
There is 1 disk moving from 2==>1
There are/is 1 disk(s) moving from 2==>3
There is 1 disk moving from 1==>3
```

Comment: You left out a step.  Say you have three disks on pole 1.  You move the top two from pole 1 to pole 3; then you move those two from pole 3 to pole 2.  Where's the third disk?

Comment: -2??? Wow, what did I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nDisks` tells the method how many disks are to be moved. It is not an identification or the number of disks being moved at one particular time but the *rest of the job* in one particular place.

Thus. There will always be one disk moving from one peg to another, never 2. You do `(nDisks-1)` in myStep where you should have done `1`. Or put more simply, myStep could have been: `myStep =  hanoi(1, fromPole, toPole);`

Other than that your output of the moves are correct. That means you can increase to more disks and expect correct moves.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I outputted the wrong information. My results were fine, it was just my information that threw me off